# Android studio: Kotlin scope functions Unresolved reference. But Project compiles

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am facing this strange issue where my project compiles and runs successfully but in my kotlin scope functions red errors are coming. It also shows errors on some of the kotlin functions like toLong(), toDouble() etc.

[image: Where the let shows unresolved reference]

and I have this in my gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    def room_version = "beta01"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //android X
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    api 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    api 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.20'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.0-$room_version"
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    api(name: 'sdk-release-1.6.1', ext: 'aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    //annotation processors
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-$room_version"
    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    //facebook app events sdk
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

Gradle Properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

build gradle

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried Invalidate cache/Restart and also tried deleting .idea and .gradle files nothing helped, I have also tried to restart the android studio and also tried to change branches from git nothing helped.
any help appreciated.

Comment: Try to use kotlin 1.3.60. They are almost compatible

Comment: This finally solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: would you suggest the coroutine version as well for the same issue? @Vlad

Comment: The latest version is `1.3.2` [bintray](https://bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/kotlinx.coroutines), it uses kotlin `1.3.50`. I think it doesn't matter, gradle will use the latest version

Comment: Here is with 1.3.60 https://bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/kotlinx.coroutines/1.3.2-1.3.60

Comment: Now i am facing different issues like id, string, layouts are also giving same issue unresolved reference

Comment: it was necessary to install Linux) This is a meme in Russia

Comment: Not getting, what meme?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme

Comment: May be a good meme, but I am still facing the issues, now  unresolved reference for layout, string and id. Basically R.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203448/discussion-between-ice-spirit-and-vlad).

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I faced same problem. Nothing works. So I copy the app folder and replace it with copied one. deleted .idea and .gradle and replaced it from previous one. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience on Android Studio with Kotlin since 2 weeks ago.
When I import a project on GitHub with old Kotlin plugin version `1.3.31`. I quickly changed it to `1.3.72` (the latest kotlin) then, I had had this error too.

I could fix the error when I changed the plugin version to `1.3.61` (older version) and sync my project. It removed the error and update it to the latest plugin version `1.3.72`. And everything worked smoothly now.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0-alpha06"
    }
}
```

I was like magic.

Just changed the  Kotlin plugin version to a 2 or 3 older versions **backward** and sync your project. I should work

I hoped it helps

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50'
```

Into

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.50'
```

And then do again, clean build then invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Still facing same issue

Comment: Can you show you whole app build.gradle and project build.gradle along with gradle.properties and local.properties