# How does one define scopes when using GoogleSignInOptions.requestScopes() for Gmail API?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gmail-api, google-signin

#### Question:

How does one define a Gmail API scope for a `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder()`?

#### Summary:

I have an Android app written in Kotlin, in which I am attempting to integrate a call to the Gmail API, though can not add the `GMAIL_READONLY` scope when requesting scopes.

#### Relevant Information & What I've tried:

From the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#configure_google_sign-in_and_the_googlesigninclient_object):

> ...to configure Google Sign-In to request users' ID and basic profile information, create a `GoogleSignInOptions` object with the `DEFAULT_SIGN_IN` parameter. To request users' email addresses as well, create the `GoogleSignInOptions` object with the `requestEmail` option.
>
> If you need to request additional scopes to access Google APIs, specify them with `requestScopes`.

I have in my application gradle file the Google API client and Gmail service dependencies taken from the [Java Gmail Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java):

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev83-1.23.0'
```

And in the corresponding fragment I have a `setOnClickListener{}` for a button which is to make the API call. Following the steps on the previously linked "Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App" page, I have the following code snippet:

```kotlin
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.google_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener {
            val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
}
```

I am however having build errors when I attempt to add the Gmail.READONLY scope.

#### Examples:

Using the following declaration

```
val gmailScope = Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY)
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .requestScopes(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY)
    .build()
```

gives a `Type mismatch` error, for which the required type is `Scope` and `GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY` is of type String. The Gmail Java Quickstart uses a String List for defininf scopes with:

```
Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
```

However integrating this with

```
.requestScopes(Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS))
```

gives the same type error, naturally with a Mutable `List<String>` instead of the previous String.

The `Scope` class as documented on this [Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Scope) page defines the constructor to be:

> `Scope(String scopeUri)`:  Creates a new scope with the given URI.

So I attempted an implementation using this class as such:

```
val gmailScope = Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY)
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .requestScopes(gmailScope)
    .build()
```

and also directly with the URI:

```
val gmailScope = Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly")
```

However this gives an `Unresolved refernce: Scope` error. I followed the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112993) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `.kt` file is missing the `Scope` class import from `android.gms.common.api`.*

#### Import line:

```kt
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
```