# Kotlin extension functions unresolved reference : navGraphViewModels

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to convert some part my code from java to kotlin. Currently, I am facing a problem.
To scope a viewmodel to NavGrap im using

```
private val mPrintsViewModel : PrintsViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_print)
```

It compiles fine. But I get an error while running the app.

```
Unresolved reference: navGraphViewModels
```

I viewed several solutions like

1. Add following lines to gradle

```
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

2. Clear cache and restart
3. Verify if the IDE kotlin version matches with the project kotlin version.

None of the above solutions work.

This issue happens for all kotlin extension functions.

I am using kotlin-1.4.10

Similar question : [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169562/unresolved-reference-kotlinx), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112993/android-studio-kotlin-scope-functions-unresolved-reference-but-project-compile)

Comment: Check the code is actually in a Fragment. You cannot access it from an Activity etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `navGraphViewModels` property delegate is part of the `navigation-fragment-ktx` dependency. It isn't part of Kotlin, nor part of the `kotlin-android` or `kotlin-android-extensions` plugins.

Make sure your `dependencies` block has a dependency on `navigation-fragment-ktx` (and specifically not just `navigation-fragment`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it has the dependency 
```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1"
```